# What is the meaning of the word 'community vineyards'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I recently came across the term 'community vineyards.' From the context, the speaker was referring to a community meeting. The only definition of the word 'vineyard' is related to grape plantations from the internet. Did I mishear, or is this term specific to Texas, US?

Full context: `"X, Y, Z were the popular demands during community vineyards."`

Comment: What was the **full** context? Please edit your question to include that information.

Comment: It looks like a weird mistake, maybe an autocorrect error, or maybe the person was thinking of wine while they were typing. Meetings are often named after a space where they're held, e.g. a town hall or a market square, although a vineyard seems a strange place. It is very hard to see what it might be a mistake for; maybe they have a meeting in a "barnyard".

Comment: Google shows there are vineyards with meeting rooms (not surprising as many have bars, restaurants, or hotels), and there are also churches called [Vineyard](https://vineyardusa.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I've heard of "community gardens" in the USA, which are gardens managed and operated by groups of local volunteers. My assumption would be that a "community vineyard" is the same thing, but specifically for grapes!

As @randomhead alluded to, context is important. If you can provide more context, I might interpret the meaning differently.